# Count time between hardware interrupts [STM32]

Tags: events, timer, stm32, interrupt

I try to produce a moving average function and count a time between period update events. Description of function — please see comments near code.

*(I know there are another options possible like input capture, I still want to make it on this way):*

This IRQ Handler will be activated when propeller passing a light gate (hardware interrupt):

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)  
{
  if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET) //when high state
  {
    //***************************************************************
    //count up a interruptcounter
    //get actual TIM10 CNT value (microsecond timer)
    //actual microsecond counter is a new us_value + (65536 * number of periods (16 bit*periods)) - last us_value
    //save new us_value like old us_value for a next loop
    //***************************************************************
    interruptcounter[0]++; 
    new_uscounter[0] = TIM10 -> CNT; 
    uscounter[0] = new_uscounter[0] + (65536*period_cnt) - old_uscounter[0];  
    old_uscounter[0] = new_uscounter[0]; 
    //***************************************************************
    //Get current time in us
    //Set dynamic value of last calculated mean time
    //Calculating a new mean time
    //((last mean time + new received time)/count of interrupts)
    //***************************************************************
    current_time_us[0] = uscounter[0];
    dynamic_mean_time[0] = dynamic_mean_time[0] + current_time_us[0];
    mean_time[0] = dynamic_mean_time[0] / interruptcounter[0];
    uscounter[0] = 0;
    current_time_us[0] = 0;
    EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
  }
}
```

I get wrong (different) values  for mean_time, propeller are rotating with same speed.
[image: timer function]

Of course of STM32 16-bit register, I get values from TIM10->CNT between 0 and 65536.
So, to calculate a time between HW interrupts I have 3 cases:

1. new us value is > than old us value within one period
2. new us value is > than old us value within n*periods (register overflow -> update event counter)
3. new us value is < than old us value within n * periods

So, I think the code part:

```
uscounter[0] = new_uscounter[0] + (65536 * period_cnt) - old_uscounter[0];
```

should solve this problem. But something went wrong. Thank you for your help in advice!

Here is a debug output of uscounter[0] by starting and slow rotating (with a same speed) of propeller:

```
debug_cnt[0]    volatile uint16_t   0   
debug_cnt[1]    volatile uint16_t   31297   
debug_cnt[2]    volatile uint16_t   48125   
debug_cnt[3]    volatile uint16_t   11589   
debug_cnt[4]    volatile uint16_t   3816    
debug_cnt[5]    volatile uint16_t   4129    
debug_cnt[6]    volatile uint16_t   5730    
debug_cnt[7]    volatile uint16_t   7886    
debug_cnt[8]    volatile uint16_t   9594    
debug_cnt[9]    volatile uint16_t   11881   
debug_cnt[10]   volatile uint16_t   13614   
debug_cnt[11]   volatile uint16_t   15939   
debug_cnt[12]   volatile uint16_t   17753   
debug_cnt[13]   volatile uint16_t   20092   
debug_cnt[14]   volatile uint16_t   21792   
debug_cnt[15]   volatile uint16_t   24045   
debug_cnt[16]   volatile uint16_t   25696   
debug_cnt[17]   volatile uint16_t   27882   
debug_cnt[18]   volatile uint16_t   29378   
debug_cnt[19]   volatile uint16_t   31470   
debug_cnt[20]   volatile uint16_t   32714   
debug_cnt[21]   volatile uint16_t   34735   
debug_cnt[22]   volatile uint16_t   35838   
debug_cnt[23]   volatile uint16_t   37637   
debug_cnt[24]   volatile uint16_t   38707   
debug_cnt[25]   volatile uint16_t   40296   
debug_cnt[26]   volatile uint16_t   41028   
debug_cnt[27]   volatile uint16_t   42470   
debug_cnt[28]   volatile uint16_t   43056   
debug_cnt[29]   volatile uint16_t   44311   
debug_cnt[30]   volatile uint16_t   44646   
debug_cnt[31]   volatile uint16_t   45705   
debug_cnt[32]   volatile uint16_t   45871   
debug_cnt[33]   volatile uint16_t   46986   
debug_cnt[34]   volatile uint16_t   47321   
debug_cnt[35]   volatile uint16_t   48264   
debug_cnt[36]   volatile uint16_t   48287   
debug_cnt[37]   volatile uint16_t   49149   
debug_cnt[38]   volatile uint16_t   49090   
debug_cnt[39]   volatile uint16_t   49985   
debug_cnt[40]   volatile uint16_t   50223   
debug_cnt[41]   volatile uint16_t   50931   
debug_cnt[42]   volatile uint16_t   50607   
debug_cnt[43]   volatile uint16_t   51195   
debug_cnt[44]   volatile uint16_t   50890   
debug_cnt[45]   volatile uint16_t   51570   
debug_cnt[46]   volatile uint16_t   51322   
debug_cnt[47]   volatile uint16_t   51658   
debug_cnt[48]   volatile uint16_t   51025   
debug_cnt[49]   volatile uint16_t   51363   
debug_cnt[50]   volatile uint16_t   50919   
debug_cnt[51]   volatile uint16_t   51325   
debug_cnt[52]   volatile uint16_t   50816   
debug_cnt[53]   volatile uint16_t   51133   
debug_cnt[54]   volatile uint16_t   50608   
debug_cnt[55]   volatile uint16_t   51002   
debug_cnt[56]   volatile uint16_t   50630   
debug_cnt[57]   volatile uint16_t   51074   
debug_cnt[58]   volatile uint16_t   50601   
debug_cnt[59]   volatile uint16_t   51045   
debug_cnt[60]   volatile uint16_t   50579   
debug_cnt[61]   volatile uint16_t   51111   
debug_cnt[62]   volatile uint16_t   51052   
debug_cnt[63]   volatile uint16_t   51495   
debug_cnt[64]   volatile uint16_t   50990   
debug_cnt[65]   volatile uint16_t   51444   
debug_cnt[66]   volatile uint16_t   51088   
debug_cnt[67]   volatile uint16_t   51630   
debug_cnt[68]   volatile uint16_t   51280   
debug_cnt[69]   volatile uint16_t   51723   
debug_cnt[70]   volatile uint16_t   51327   
debug_cnt[71]   volatile uint16_t   51956   
debug_cnt[72]   volatile uint16_t   51812   
debug_cnt[73]   volatile uint16_t   52238   
debug_cnt[74]   volatile uint16_t   51725   
debug_cnt[75]   volatile uint16_t   52021   
debug_cnt[76]   volatile uint16_t   51390   
debug_cnt[77]   volatile uint16_t   51789   
debug_cnt[78]   volatile uint16_t   51594   
debug_cnt[79]   volatile uint16_t   51854   
debug_cnt[80]   volatile uint16_t   51210   
debug_cnt[81]   volatile uint16_t   51565   
debug_cnt[82]   volatile uint16_t   51098   
debug_cnt[83]   volatile uint16_t   51726   
debug_cnt[84]   volatile uint16_t   51512   
debug_cnt[85]   volatile uint16_t   51894   
debug_cnt[86]   volatile uint16_t   51364   
debug_cnt[87]   volatile uint16_t   51806   
debug_cnt[88]   volatile uint16_t   51486   
debug_cnt[89]   volatile uint16_t   51961   
debug_cnt[90]   volatile uint16_t   51596   
debug_cnt[91]   volatile uint16_t   52028   
debug_cnt[92]   volatile uint16_t   51586   
debug_cnt[93]   volatile uint16_t   53226   
debug_cnt[94]   volatile uint16_t   61045   
debug_cnt[95]   volatile uint16_t   18419   
debug_cnt[96]   volatile uint16_t   57780   
debug_cnt[97]   volatile uint16_t   33502   
debug_cnt[98]   volatile uint16_t   0   
debug_cnt[99]   volatile uint16_t   0
```

And this is a uscounter[0] by middle speed of propeller:

```
    debug_cnt[0]    volatile uint16_t   0   
    debug_cnt[1]    volatile uint16_t   49142   
    debug_cnt[2]    volatile uint16_t   53649   
    debug_cnt[3]    volatile uint16_t   10472   
    debug_cnt[4]    volatile uint16_t   3516    
    debug_cnt[5]    volatile uint16_t   64934   
    debug_cnt[6]    volatile uint16_t   40194   
    debug_cnt[7]    volatile uint16_t   25799   
    debug_cnt[8]    volatile uint16_t   20616   
    debug_cnt[9]    volatile uint16_t   18153   
    debug_cnt[10]   volatile uint16_t   16844   
    debug_cnt[11]   volatile uint16_t   15920   
    debug_cnt[12]   volatile uint16_t   15367   
    debug_cnt[13]   volatile uint16_t   14854   
    debug_cnt[14]   volatile uint16_t   14556   
    debug_cnt[15]   volatile uint16_t   14235   
    debug_cnt[16]   volatile uint16_t   14067   
    debug_cnt[17]   volatile uint16_t   13849   
    debug_cnt[18]   volatile uint16_t   13753   
    debug_cnt[19]   volatile uint16_t   13596   
    debug_cnt[20]   volatile uint16_t   13545   
    debug_cnt[21]   volatile uint16_t   13428   
    debug_cnt[22]   volatile uint16_t   13408   
    debug_cnt[23]   volatile uint16_t   14412   
    debug_cnt[24]   volatile uint16_t   12184   
    debug_cnt[25]   volatile uint16_t   13204   
    debug_cnt[26]   volatile uint16_t   13207   
    debug_cnt[27]   volatile uint16_t   13130   
    debug_cnt[28]   volatile uint16_t   13143   
    debug_cnt[29]   volatile uint16_t   13071   
    debug_cnt[30]   volatile uint16_t   13088   
    debug_cnt[31]   volatile uint16_t   13020   
    debug_cnt[32]   volatile uint16_t   13035   
    debug_cnt[33]   volatile uint16_t   12969   
    debug_cnt[34]   volatile uint16_t   12990   
    debug_cnt[35]   volatile uint16_t   12925   
    debug_cnt[36]   volatile uint16_t   12950   
    debug_cnt[37]   volatile uint16_t   12891   
    debug_cnt[38]   volatile uint16_t   12918   
    debug_cnt[39]   volatile uint16_t   12863   
    debug_cnt[40]   volatile uint16_t   12893   
    debug_cnt[41]   volatile uint16_t   12841   
    //----------------------------------------
    debug_cnt[745]  volatile uint16_t   12677   
    debug_cnt[746]  volatile uint16_t   12720   
    debug_cnt[747]  volatile uint16_t   12678   
    debug_cnt[748]  volatile uint16_t   12721   
    debug_cnt[749]  volatile uint16_t   12678   
    debug_cnt[750]  volatile uint16_t   12722   
    debug_cnt[751]  volatile uint16_t   12743   
    debug_cnt[752]  volatile uint16_t   12914   
    debug_cnt[753]  volatile uint16_t   13031   
    debug_cnt[754]  volatile uint16_t   13245   
    debug_cnt[755]  volatile uint16_t   13372   
    debug_cnt[756]  volatile uint16_t   13593   
    debug_cnt[757]  volatile uint16_t   13725   
    debug_cnt[758]  volatile uint16_t   13954   
    debug_cnt[759]  volatile uint16_t   14092   
    debug_cnt[760]  volatile uint16_t   14329   
    debug_cnt[761]  volatile uint16_t   14479   
    debug_cnt[762]  volatile uint16_t   14726   
    debug_cnt[763]  volatile uint16_t   14881   
    debug_cnt[764]  volatile uint16_t   15138   
    debug_cnt[765]  volatile uint16_t   15298   
    debug_cnt[766]  volatile uint16_t   15565   
    debug_cnt[767]  volatile uint16_t   15733   
    debug_cnt[768]  volatile uint16_t   16009   
    debug_cnt[769]  volatile uint16_t   16185   
    debug_cnt[770]  volatile uint16_t   16472   
    debug_cnt[771]  volatile uint16_t   16653   
    debug_cnt[772]  volatile uint16_t   16952   
    debug_cnt[773]  volatile uint16_t   17141   
    debug_cnt[774]  volatile uint16_t   17451   
    debug_cnt[775]  volatile uint16_t   17650   
    debug_cnt[776]  volatile uint16_t   17970   
    debug_cnt[777]  volatile uint16_t   18179   
    debug_cnt[778]  volatile uint16_t   18515   
    debug_cnt[779]  volatile uint16_t   18734   
    debug_cnt[780]  volatile uint16_t   19082   
    debug_cnt[781]  volatile uint16_t   19312   
    debug_cnt[782]  volatile uint16_t   19675   
    debug_cnt[783]  volatile uint16_t   19917   
    debug_cnt[784]  volatile uint16_t   20298   
    debug_cnt[785]  volatile uint16_t   20554   
    debug_cnt[786]  volatile uint16_t   20957   
    debug_cnt[787]  volatile uint16_t   21227   
    debug_cnt[788]  volatile uint16_t   21650   
    debug_cnt[789]  volatile uint16_t   21940   
    debug_cnt[790]  volatile uint16_t   22386   
    debug_cnt[791]  volatile uint16_t   22695   
    debug_cnt[792]  volatile uint16_t   23164   
    debug_cnt[793]  volatile uint16_t   23492   
    debug_cnt[794]  volatile uint16_t   23988   
    debug_cnt[795]  volatile uint16_t   24338   
    debug_cnt[796]  volatile uint16_t   24865   
    debug_cnt[797]  volatile uint16_t   25240   
    debug_cnt[798]  volatile uint16_t   25800   
    debug_cnt[799]  volatile uint16_t   26205   
[800...899] volatile uint16_t [100] 0x20000830 <debug_cnt+1600> 
    debug_cnt[800]  volatile uint16_t   26799   
    debug_cnt[801]  volatile uint16_t   27235   
    debug_cnt[802]  volatile uint16_t   27872   
    debug_cnt[803]  volatile uint16_t   28343   
    debug_cnt[804]  volatile uint16_t   29026   
    debug_cnt[805]  volatile uint16_t   29541   
    debug_cnt[806]  volatile uint16_t   30279   
    debug_cnt[807]  volatile uint16_t   30842   
    debug_cnt[808]  volatile uint16_t   31639   
    debug_cnt[809]  volatile uint16_t   32257   
    debug_cnt[810]  volatile uint16_t   33128   
    debug_cnt[811]  volatile uint16_t   33812   
    debug_cnt[812]  volatile uint16_t   34773   
    debug_cnt[813]  volatile uint16_t   35544   
    debug_cnt[814]  volatile uint16_t   36597   
    debug_cnt[815]  volatile uint16_t   37458   
    debug_cnt[816]  volatile uint16_t   38626   
    debug_cnt[817]  volatile uint16_t   39590   
    debug_cnt[818]  volatile uint16_t   40883   
    debug_cnt[819]  volatile uint16_t   41976   
    debug_cnt[820]  volatile uint16_t   43429   
    debug_cnt[821]  volatile uint16_t   44684   
    debug_cnt[822]  volatile uint16_t   46351   
    debug_cnt[823]  volatile uint16_t   0   
    debug_cnt[824]  volatile uint16_t   0
```

Both parts of the code are captured in 10 seconds.

Comment: It's difficult to help you since you didn't giev an example of the values you compute for  `uscounter`. Did you try to increase the timer tick , first to avoid any overflow and check that your GPIO interrupt is really regular ? Also did you try to break inside the handler and read value of `uscounter`?

Comment: Hello Guillaume, I just added a part with values.

Comment: The values from middle parts is okay: by slow rotating motor about 50000us/rotating and by middle rotating around 13000us/rotating, but the start and stop values jumping:
see from debug_cnt[0] to debug_cnt[7]

Answer (score 0):

It was so one noob error — I declare uscounter, new_uscounter, old_uscounter, current_time_us, dynamic_mean_time, mean_time like **volatile uint_16t** variables!
And uint_16t get just 65535 value - so it was overflow of variable — **changing to uint_32t** solves the problem!